# Strange reference behavior of Color and SolidColorBrush in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-assembly, windows-10-universal

I'm facing some strange behavior of Color and SolidColorBrush.
The code is as follows
[image]

I have to use picture to show the strange part. I have Windows reference in the project but when I hover over Color it says that "Color is inaccessible due to its protection level" and at this time I have my namespaces  like this
[image]

Then I removed using Windows.UI. When I hover back again to Color, it recommend me to add `using Windows.UI` and I followed the instruction and it added `using Windows.UI` back and it works now! It seems like these two `using Windows.UI`s are different It will also add the reference `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`. And then, it will build and works fine in my local machine but fail in my build server. I'm wondering why this will happen because I don't think `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` is necessary and is the reason that cause build server fail to compile it. Hope I explain it understandable...

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your problem? When I tested your code in my side, everything works well. I only need to add `using Windows.UI;` in the code and there is no `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` reference. Have you tested your code in other machines? Do they have the same issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I haven't got chance to test it in other machines yet. The strange thing is that, in my other projects in the same solution, it worked totally fine for SolidColorBrush and Color. Only Windows reference will be added. Only one project has this strange behavior, the using Windows.UI; that I typed in is useless and by clicking potential fix, it will add this back in the code and also System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.   I tried to refactor the code and write some converters to put it into other project to dodge this problem and make code more readable.